# AVAudioPlayerNode cancel scheduled

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayernode

The AVAudioPlayerNode stop() function " Clear all of the node's previously scheduled events and stop playback. "

Need to clear all the node's previously scheduled without stopping the player. Any idea ?

Comment: I would try to calculate where the player is currently, then `.stop()`, and then schedule the current buffer again at the current frame of the sound using `scheduleSegment(_:startingFrame:frameCount:at:completionHandler:)`. Not sure how seamless this would be though

Comment: did you find a solution>